# change the input's field width based on the name attribute

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a question and answer input field. I'm storing the answer in the name attribute for easy checking later.
How do I make the input field the same length as the string in the input's field name attribute?

```
<input class="field" type="text" name="answer">
```

so for example the above input field should be six characters long.

Comment: the size of a character is not the same depending on the character, the font, the font-size, etc ... so there isn't really a *six characters long*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `JavaScript` to accomplish this.

```js
const fields = document.querySelectorAll('.field');
fields.forEach(field => {
  const name = field.getAttribute('name'); 
  field.setAttribute('size', name.length);
  field.value = name;
});
```

```css
.field {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<input class="field" type="text" name="answer">
<input class="field" type="text" name="another_answer">
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working when i run the code snippet. They are both the same size.

Comment: @Spanishbeginner I've updated the example to use the `size` attribute, since you didn't specify how the sizing should work.

Comment: @Spanishbeginner Using `monospace`, the `size` matches up with the characters in the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!