# Is it possible to resize input field width according to attribute name

Tags: html, css

How do I make the input field the same length as the string in the input's field name attribute?

```html
<input class="field" type="text" name="data">
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54974994/change-the-inputs-field-width-based-on-the-name-attribute/54975017#54975017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify maximum length and maximum size using the following:

```
<input type="text" name="data" maxlength="4" size="4">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input name="data" type="text" size=4 maxlength=4 >
```

Comment: Adding a little bit details would definitely help !!